# Did Judas betray Jesus' carnal mission?

Tags: jesus

> But Jesus said unto him, Judas, betrayest thou the Son of man with a kiss? (Lk. 22:48 KJV)

Why didn't Jesus tell Judas that he was betraying the Son of God? In what sense could Jesus' flesh have been betrayed?

Comment: I think you need to explain what you mean by 'carnal mission'.

Comment: Was Jesus' reign by David's succession a carnal mission?  John 18:37

Answer (score 3):

The main question refers to "Jesus' carnal mission" without saying what that mission is understood to have been. The phrase never occurs even once in the entire Bible. This means that no hermeneutical approach can even start there. The secondary question (in the comments) asks, "Why didn't Jesus tell Judas that he was betraying the Son of God?" The third question asks, "In what sense could Jesus' flesh have been betrayed?" The one scripture text that apparently deals with all three question is Luke 22:48.

Given that I cannot begin to understand the main question, I will start with the last one and try to work backwards.

This calls for a simple answer, as it is a simple question - **'In what sense could Jesus' flesh have been betrayed?'** Jesus the man had flesh and blood. Jesus the man was betrayed by Judas Iscariot into the hands of men who sought to kill him - to render his flesh lifeless. The betrayal enabled that to happen, and thus was Jesus the man betrayed in his flesh (or, 'as' flesh.)

The second question is - **"Why didn't Jesus tell Judas that he was betraying the Son of God?"** That was because Jesus knew Judas was only thinking of him in terms of flesh and blood. Judas was not thinking of Jesus in terms of being the Son of God. Peter did, that time Jesus asked him who he thought the Son of Man was - Jesus rejoiced that the penny had finally dropped with Peter who then declared Jesus to be the Christ, the Son of the living God. "Flesh and blood hath not revealed it unto thee, but my Father which is in heaven." Matthew 16:13-17. Divine revelation opened Peter's eyes. Not so with Judas, who had had Satan enter into him a few hours earlier. Judas was spoken to by Jesus as Judas thought, for he was beyond redemption at that point of betrayal.

Now the main question - **"Did Judas betray Jesus' carnal mission?"** Judas might have thought his betrayal would force Jesus into carrying out an earthly mission. Judas wrongly supposed Jesus' real mission was to set up an earthly (carnal) government in Jerusalem, overthrowing the hated Roman rule. He was wrong. Nothing Judas did could thwart Jesus succeeding in accomplishing his divine mission, which required him to die as the only sinless sacrifice for sin there ever has been.

If Judas had had the faintest idea about that heavenly truth, he would never have betrayed Jesus. Judas was carnal. Judas's mission was carnal. Judas succeeded in carrying out his carnal mission against flesh and blood, but because Jesus was both Son of Man and Son of God, he triumphed while Judas took his own life upon realisation of his utter failure and desolation. Judas betrayed himself spiritually in betraying Jesus, the Son of Man, into the hands of sinful men.

Answer (score 1):

**Luke 22:53**

> "But this is your hour , and the power of darkness".

"darkness" here is spiritual. The Son of Man is about to be crucified. It is also physical darkness.  The people who came to Jesus had "lanterns and torches". [John 18:3].

In the darkness are his disciples [John 18:1] and Jesus, some 12 men. In the flickering light of the torches Judas is able to recognise the clothes, shape and face of Jesus to make sure the soldiers and some officers get the right man. The chief priests and the Pharasees who sent the soldiers might have recognised Jesus from their encouters with Him in the temple. But the soldiers unaided would be less likely to have recognised Jesus.

Judas knew where to find Jesus, he "knew the place" [John 18:2] and that they would be there. "Jesus often met there with his disciples",  [John 18:2].